# Eliminate similar cycles in directed graph

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following data:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblLoop
(
    person1 varchar(20),
    person2 varchar(20),
    ColDate date,
);

INSERT INTO tblLoop VALUES('A','B','2020-01-01'),('A','C','2020-01-01'),('A','D','2020-01-01'),
                          ('B','E','2020-01-02'),('B','F','2020-01-02'),
                          ('D','G','2020-01-03'),('D','H','2020-01-03'),
                          ('F','i','2020-01-04'),
                          ('G','J','2020-01-05'),
                          ('i','A','2020-01-06'),
                          ('J','D','2020-01-07'),
                          ('X','Y','2020-01-08'),('X','Z','2020-01-08'),
                          ('Z','X','2020-01-09'),
                          ('Y','W','2020-01-09');
```

Records Look like:

[image]
[image]

Requirement: I need to find the persons which forms a cycle. For an example in the given data we found 3 Cycle's:

Cycle 1: `A` connected with `B` connected with `F` connected with `i` connected with `A`.

Cycle 2: `A` connected with `D` connected with `G` connected with `J` connected with `D`.

Cycle 3: `X` connected with `Z` connected with `X`.

Expected result:

```
LoopFound
--------------------
A->B->F->i->A
A->D->G->J->D
X->Z->X
```

My try:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
      SELECT Person1, Person2, 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (','+ Person1+ ','+ Person2+ ',')) AS nodes, 1 AS lev, 
             (CASE WHEN Person1 = Person2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_cycle
      FROM tblLoop e
      UNION ALL
      SELECT cte.Person1, e.Person2,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (cte.nodes+ e.Person2+ ',')), lev + 1,
             (CASE WHEN cte.nodes LIKE ('%,'+ e.Person2+ ',%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_cycle
      FROM CTE 
      JOIN tblLoop e ON e.Person1 = cte.Person2
      WHERE cte.has_cycle = 0 
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE has_cycle = 1;
```

**NOTE**: Getting multiple combination of cycles from above query.

Comment: I would suggest, if possible, to add an extra flag in your table which indicates that person A and X are the root persons. In your SELECT statement you can then only filter the combinations for those persons.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment by Kevin, the answer lies in including a flag to indicate that a given node is a valid start point, and can be included in the query:

In this instance, 'A' and 'X' are given as start points, therefore we will mark all records where the originator is either 'A' or 'X':

```
CREATE TABLE #tblLoop
(
    person1 varchar(20),
    person2 varchar(20),
    ColDate date,
isRoot INT
);
INSERT INTO #tblLoop VALUES('A','B','2020-01-01',1),
                          ('A','C','2020-01-01',1),
                          ('A','D','2020-01-01',1),
                          ('B','E','2020-01-02',0),
                          ('B','F','2020-01-02',0),
                          ('D','G','2020-01-03',0),
                          ('D','H','2020-01-03',0),
                          ('F','i','2020-01-04',0),
                          ('G','J','2020-01-05',0),
                          ('i','A','2020-01-06',0),
                          ('J','D','2020-01-07',0),
                          ('X','Y','2020-01-08',1),
                          ('X','Z','2020-01-08',1),
                          ('Z','X','2020-01-09',0),
                          ('Y','W','2020-01-09',0);
```

Then the following query can be amended as follows:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
      SELECT Person1, Person2, isRoot,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (','+ Person1+ ','+ Person2+ ',')) AS nodes, 1 AS lev, 
             (CASE WHEN Person1 = Person2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_cycle
      FROM #tblLoop e
      UNION ALL
      SELECT cte.Person1, e.Person2, cte.isRoot,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (cte.nodes+ e.Person2+ ',')), lev + 1,
             (CASE WHEN cte.nodes LIKE ('%,'+ e.Person2+ ',%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_cycle
      FROM CTE 
      JOIN #tblLoop e ON e.Person1 = cte.Person2
      WHERE cte.has_cycle = 0 
     )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE has_cycle = 1
AND isRoot = 1
```

Credit to Kevin for the idea, this is just a working implementation of it.

Comment: Is there any other way rather than setting `flag`?

Comment: I tried to find those starting node's by using query `;WITH CTE AS
 (
  SELECT t.* 
  FROM tblLoop t
  WHERE person1 IN (SELECT person2 FROM tblLoop t2 WHERE t.ColDate <= t2.ColDate ) OR
        person2 IN (SELECT person1 FROM tblLoop t3 WHERE t.ColDate <= t3.ColDate )
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT person1
 FROM CTE 
 WHERE person1 NOT IN (SELECT person2 FROM CTE);` Let me know your view.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following two steps:

**Step 1**: In this step, Find the start node's of the graph.

```
--Create table to store start nodes
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Temp_tblLoop', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE dbo.Temp_tblLoop; 
END

--Query to find start nodes.
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.* 
    FROM tblLoop t
    WHERE person1 IN (SELECT person2 FROM tblLoop t2 WHERE t.ColDate<= t2.ColDate) OR
          person2 IN (SELECT person1 FROM tblLoop t3 WHERE t.ColDate<= t3.ColDate)
)
SELECT DISTINCT person1 INTO Temp_tblLoop
FROM CTE 
WHERE person1 NOT IN (SELECT person2 FROM CTE);
```

**Step 2**: Find out the cycles in the graph (Excluding Similar Cycles)

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
      SELECT Person1, Person2, 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (Person1+ '->'+ Person2)) AS nodes, 1 AS lev, 
             (CASE WHEN Person1 = Person2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_cycle
      FROM tblLoop e WHERE person1 IN (SELECT person1 FROM Temp_tblLoop)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT cte.Person1, e.Person2,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (cte.nodes+'->'+ e.Person2)), lev + 1,
             (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(e.Person2, cte.nodes) != 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS has_cycle
      FROM CTE 
      JOIN tblLoop e ON e.Person1 = cte.Person2
      WHERE cte.has_cycle = 0 
     )
SELECT Person1 AS Start, Person2 AS [End],
       nodes AS Links,
       lev AS Levels     
FROM CTE
WHERE has_cycle = 1;
```

Let me your reviews, if anything needs to be done for betterment.